# Нужна помощь с sql запросом.

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица (wp_postmeta), структура такая:

```
id post_id   key            value
1    11    fromcity_1       Москва
2    11    fromdistrict_1   Садовое кольцо
3    11    fromcity_2       Воронеж
4    11    fromdistrict_1   Коминтерновский
5    13    fromcity_2       Воронеж
6    13    fromdistrict_1   Северный
```

Как мне получить `post_id`, где `%fromcity_% = Москва`, а `%fromdistrict_% = Садовое кольцо`?

Comment: EAV-style:

    select distinct p.id 
    from posts p
      join postmeta pm1 on p.id = pm1.post_id and pm1.key like 'fromcity_%' 
      join postmeta pm2 on p.id = pm2.post_id and pm2.key like 'fromdistrict_%'
    where
      pm1.value = 'Москва'
      and pm2.value = 'Садовое кольцо';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без подзапросов и диких джойнов не получится, наверное:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM wp_postmeta AS p
WHERE p.`key` LIKE 'fromcity_%' AND p.`value` = 'Москва'
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM wp_postmeta AS c
        WHERE c.post_id = p.post_id
            AND c.`key` LIKE `fromdistrict_%`
            AND c.`value` = 'Садовое кольцо'
    )
```

Comment: Ну, вот и я хочу без подзапросов сделать...

Comment: @RattleSneyk тут важно ответить на два вопроса:

1. Что именно произойдет, если будет подзапрос?
2. Возможно ли получить эти данные без подзапроса?

Comment: Да все. Я просто думал, что можно как то укоротить запрос=)

Comment: такой запрос будет сильно хуже, предложенного @msi. dependent subquery приведет к том, что для каждого поста из москвы будет выполнен запрос по районам. т.е. 100 постов 101 запрос. и дальше будет естественно только хуже.
ну и если будет что fromcity_1 и fromcity_2 оба будут москва, получим дубли, поэтому как минимум distinct.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT post_id
FROM wp_postmeta AS p
WHERE 
(p.`key` LIKE 'fromcity_%' AND p.`value` = 'Москва')
OR
(p.`key` LIKE `fromdistrict_%` AND p.`value` = 'Садовое кольцо')
group by post_id
having count(*)=2
```

Comment: тут `having count(*)>=2` тоже надо, юзеры могут сломать все.